# Mobile browser emulators

Tags: mobile, browser, emulation

Please do anyone have a good idea about mobile browser emulator. I don't mean mobile emulator, I want to test my site on mobile browser. I downloaded Opera 12.1 mobile emulator but it's not giving me the desired result I want. Please what fast and easy emulator can I download?

Answer (score 0):

There are many online and offline tools available, listing few of them:

https://www.responsinator.com/

Responsinator work for localhost too.

http://responsivepx.com

https://www.browserstack.com

To test in IE 8-11 and Edge, download virtual machines

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

will be adding more soon, enjoy testing:)

Comment: I just need offline emulators, because am using WAMP local server. But let me try them

Comment: I have tried them all. They still not match my test. I just need something like the Opera emulator but the problem with opera emulator, it doesn't show Font-awesome icons and images with a url source